# Modifying Termination protection of Cloud-formation stack based on tags using boto3

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I am quite new at working with Boto3. My requirements are to create a boto3 script that will modify the termination protection of Cloud Formation Stack based on tags: For Example, if the tag Value is "Production" then it will enable the termination protection and when tag Value is "Development" it will disable the termination protection. I tried working on it but got stuck somewhere and not able to get the StackName. It keeps on giving me the error that StackName CloudFormation object has no attribute 'StackName'.
Your guidance will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

For now I am filtering the stack which has the status of CREATE_COMPLETE, I am able to filter and print the number of the stacks which are  currently running but not able to print the name of the stack. Here is my code:

```
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
cftresource = boto3.resource('cloudformation',region_name='eu-west-3')
cftclient = boto3.client('cloudformation',region_name='eu-west-3')
stackfilter = cftclient.list_stacks(StackStatusFilter=['CREATE_COMPLETE'])
print ('The Number of Stacks having Status CREATE_COMPLETE are:') , print(len(stackfilter['StackSummaries']))
print(stackfilter.StackName)
```

Comment: Ok. So what is your current code and why it does not work?

Comment: I mean, real python code. Update your question with the code and explain why it does not work.

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? The code related to your attempt at disabling the termination protection.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to find the solution of this problem myself so I am posting here so that if anyone else face this issue, it will be easy for them to locate:

```
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    cftresource = boto3.resource('cloudformation',region_name='eu-west-3')
    cftclient = boto3.client('cloudformation',region_name='eu-west-3')
    stackfilter = cftclient.list_stacks(StackStatusFilter=['CREATE_COMPLETE', 'UPDATE_COMPLETE' , 'ROLLBACK_COMPLETE'])
    print ('The Number of Stacks having Status CREATE_COMPLETE, UPDATE_COMPLETE and ROLLBACK_COMPLETE are:') , print(len(stackfilter['StackSummaries']))
    statuses = ['CREATE_COMPLETE' , 'UPDATE_COMPLETE' , 'ROLLBACK_COMPLETE']
    stacks = [stack for stack in cftresource.stacks.all() if stack.stack_status in statuses]
    for stack in stacks:
        print(f'Stack Name having Status of CREATE_COMPLETE, UPDATE_COMPLETE and ROLLBACK_COMPLETE are: {stack.name}')
        if len(stack.tags) > 0:
            for tag in stack.tags:
                # print(f' - Tag: {tag["Key"]}={tag["Value"]}')
                if tag["Value"] == 'Production':
                    print(f' - Tag: {tag["Key"]}={tag["Value"]}')
                    cftclient.update_termination_protection(EnableTerminationProtection=True, StackName=stack.name)
                elif tag["Value"] == 'Development':
                    print(f' - Tag: {tag["Key"]}={tag["Value"]}')
                    cftclient.update_termination_protection(EnableTerminationProtection=False, StackName=stack.name)
                else:
                    print(f' - No Tags')
                    print('-'*60)
```